# Can't Connect to Azure VM Using RDP

Tags: windows, azure, rdp

I'm setting up a new vanilla Windows Server 2016 VM on Azure cloud, and want to connect via RDP. I followed the steps in the [Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-portal) guide, but when I try to connect from a Windows 8 client on the company LAN, I get "An internal error has occurred." When I try to connect from an Android client on the public internet, I get "We couldn't connect to the remote PC. This might be due to an expired password. If this keeps happening, contact your admin or tech support for help. Error code: 0x207".

I've already tried the following.

- Restarted the server
- Deleted and recreated the VM from scratch
- Checked the boot diagnostics screenshot (VM is on Ctrl+Alt+Del screen without showing any errors)
- Checked the network interface rules (HTTP, HTTPS, and RDP allowed on 80, 443, and 3389 respectively over TCP from any source, allowed, prioritised)
- Reset the configuration (Support + Troubleshooting > Reset password > reset configuration only)
- Changed the private IP address to a new address within the subnet (10.0.0.4 > 10.0.0.5)
- Pinged the VM using SysInternals PSPing on the public IP address, port 3389 (0% loss, average 24ms)
- I can connect using Serial console, and have checked the following:

  - Installed IIS using PS `Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools` I can view the IIS start screen from my browser using the public IP address
  - Check if the RDP is disabled by polices.

    - `reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server " /v fDenyTSConnections` > returns 0
    - `reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services" /v fDenyTSConnections` > key does not exist
  - Check the current configuration of the terminal server. `reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v TSEnabled` > key did not exist, therefore added it using `reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v TSEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f` > key added successully
  - Check whether set to drain mode `reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v TSServerDrainMode` > key does not exist
  - Check whether you can connect to the terminal server. `reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v TSUserEnabled`> returns 0
  - Check the current configuration of the RDP listener. `reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\Winstations\RDP-Tcp" /v fEnableWinStation` > returns 0
  - Check whether you can connect to the RDP listener. `reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\Winstations\RDP-Tcp" /v fLogonDisabled` > returns 0

So I've followed all the online help guides I can find, rebuilt the VM, and tried accessing the VM from two different clients on two different networks, and nothing works! Any ideas?

Comment: You mentioned you changed the IP, are  you trying to access the machine using a public or private IP?

Comment: @Sam - using the public IP to access. I just mentioned the private IP because MS suggests that as a way to force restart the NIC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have two different issues at play here.

1. You corpnet is blocking outbound RDP (3389) to public IP addresses.  This is a typical setup and you can confirm by contacting your network team.  Work-around would be to use a VPN.  A [point-to-site VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal) is the quickest way to test this.
2. The old Android RDP client has some known issues connecting to [Server 2016](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/22017aa0-4abb-4ddf-b7be-7a220f50ff45/rd-client-android-and-ipad-issues-with-server-2016).  Try the beta client, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.rdc.android.beta&hl=en

Comment: Thanks, Ken. 2 for 2.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clicking on **Connect**, Get the VM IP and try to RDP to it. You can get the VM IP from **Networking** tab.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I've tried to connect both by downloading the RDP file and typing the IP address manually.